# Right Riemann sum of divergent integral diverges

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose $f$ is continuous and decreasing with $\int_1^\infty f(x) dx = \infty$. Fix any increasing sequence $x_i \uparrow \infty$. Is it true that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty f(x_{i+1}) (x_{i+1} - x_i) = \infty$?

Comment: Certainly not. You could make $f(n)=0$ for all $n$  and have the improper integral be $\infty$.

Comment: Good point. Suppose $f$ is continuous and decreasing.

Answer (score 0):

No

You can choose  your $x_i$  such that the area under $y=f(x_{i+1})$ over each $$[x_i, x_{i+1} ]$$ is less than $$ 1/2^i$$

Then you have $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty f(x_{i+1}) (x_{i+1} - x_i) <1 $$

Comment: I meant to write a right-riemann sum ie $f(x_{i+1})$

Comment: I guessed so, but I did the left one as you had it at first.

Comment: @Matthew JungeNow see my edited version.

Comment: Would $x_i \uparrow \infty$ in this construction?

Comment: Yes, you can extend the subinterval if you wish as long as the area under f(x) and over $  [x_i, x_{i+1} ] < 1/2^i.$

Comment: Sorry for the questions, but $f$ can be non-integrable and have this property? It sounds like $\int f$ is bounded too if such a sequence exists.